# Можно ли задать в функцию параметр по умолчанию без создания класса?

Tags: python, python-3.x, консоль

Пример кода:

```
def how_many_light_sabers_do_you_own (name):
    
    if name == "Zach":
        return 18
    else:
        return 0
```

Нужно чтобы при вызове функции без аргумента, функция возвращала ноль обратно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def how_many_light_sabers_do_you_own(name=None):
    if name is None:
        return 0
    if name == "Zach":
        return 18
    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: "Нужно чтобы при вызове функции без аргумента, функция возвращала ноль обратно.", у вас другое условие в коде

Comment: @insolor но оно выполняется правильно. или нужно запилить проверку на отсутствие аргумента?

Comment: Ну технически сейчас правильно: по заданию - если нет аргумента, то 0, если если есть, то что-то другое) Но насколько я понимаю, именно проверка отсутствия аргумента нужна.